# Is it possible to update 2 columns of 2 tables using triggering in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I create 3 table whose name are customers,payments and orders.They have a same column name **customerNumber**.**customerNumber** is a primary key of **customers** table and a foreign of **payments** and **orders** table.Now I want to make a trigger whose works is to update customerNumber in payments and orders table before updating customerNumber in customers table.

my code is here:

```
create or replace trigger customers_update 
before update of customerNumber on customers 
for each row
begin
update payments,orders 
set 
payments.customerNumber = :new.customerNumber
orders.customerNumber = :new.customerNumber
where (payments.customerNumber = :old.customerNumber)
and 
(orders.customerNumber = :old.customerNumber);
end;
/
```

but it shows some problem like this

Error at line 2: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

1. create or replace trigger customers_update
2. before update of customerNumber on customers
3. for each row
4. begin

So my question is how I fix the problem ?

Comment: Line #2 is actually `update payments,orders`. The PL/SQL implementation block of the trigger starts (in this case) with `begin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two update statements:

```
update payments
    set customerNumber = :new.customerNumber
    where payments.customerNumber = :old.customerNumber;

update orders 
    set customerNumber = :new.customerNumber
    where orders.customerNumber = :old.customerNumber;
```

Oracle doesn't allow updates to two tables in the same statement.

Comment: It works I know but I want to know why is it not possible in just one update query?

Comment: @RumyHasan . . . Because Oracle does not support that functionality.  MySQL does, but Oracle doesn't.

Comment: If you can avoid doing this in trigger, and can do it at same place where you are updating the Customers table, do that.

Comment: Maybe you should wrap that in a transaction to properly emulate "multi-table update" ? As far as I remember those are atomic (in MySQL at least)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux . . . My understanding of Oracle is that triggers are all within the same transaction.  So although you would want to wrap these in a transaction in a stored procedure to get such semantics, it is not needed in a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Of course you're right: I can't find the relevant part in the official doc, but from an other source, Oracle supports [statement level atomicity](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/rollback#statement-level_rollback) and _"Any side effects of an atomic statement, for example, triggers invoked upon execution of the statement, are considered part of the atomic statement."_

Answer (score 0):

"Oracle doesn't allow updates to two tables in the same statement."

That's true, but if you really like, you can create a view and update the view.

Using a trigger with type INSTEAD OF, you can update both, but still two updates internally, but one update a functional level.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks.